# LoadRunner Script issue

Tags: loadrunner

Actually i am working on place order script in latest version of LR and web http protocol.While recording it records succesfully of placing the order but while replaying particularly the last request in the script which shows the order details, is unable to show the order placed details and the order id but the script is passing.I have done correlation and all. In Snapshot :-

Response body of recording - Order placed successfull with order id -XXXXXX and Succssflag - true

Response body of replay - Order number couldnot be found and Successflag - false

Comment: Try to compare and check the request sent while recording and replaying using Split option in snapshot view. You should be able to find some lead.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the output logs if there's an HTTP 400 or 500 response? sometimes the script gives us passed status if the affected requests are not enclosed in a transaction.